# Why won't my second method run?

Tags: java

I programmed the two parts of this assignment separately and they functioned as intended.  When I combined the parts the program will only run the first method call (drawBox) and ignores the second one (drawPattern).  What have I done wrong?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Patterns {

  public static final Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in); 

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Project 1 written by CHRISTOPHER TERRANOVA");
    System.out.println();
    drawBox();
    drawPattern();

  }

  public static void drawBox() {

    //Scanner input to determine number of boxes
    System.out.print("Enter the number of boxes desired:\n");
    int numBoxes = CONSOLE.nextInt();

    // for loop for the top half of the boxes
    System.out.print ("+");
    for (int i = 1; i<=numBoxes; i++){
      System.out.print("------+");
    }
    System.out.println();    

    // for loop for the 1st half of the middle of the boxes
    System.out.print ("|");
    for (int i = 1; i<=numBoxes; i++){
      System.out.print("      |");
    }
    System.out.println();    

    // repeated for loop for the 2nd half of the middle of the boxes
    System.out.print ("|");
    for (int i = 1; i<=numBoxes; i++){
      System.out.print("      |");
    }
    System.out.println();

    // for loop for the bottom of the boxes
    System.out.print ("+");
    for (int i = 1; i<=numBoxes; i++){
      System.out.print("------+");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void drawPattern() {

    //Scanner inputs to determine width and height of pattern
    System.out.print("Enter width of the pattern:\n");
    int width = CONSOLE.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter height of the pattern:\n");
    int height = CONSOLE.nextInt();  

    for(int i=1; i<=width; i++) {
        System.out.print(" __ ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    for(int j=1; j<=height; j++) {
        for(int i=1; i<=width; i++) {
            System.out.print("/ \\__");
        }
        System.out.println();

    for(int i=1; i<=width; i++) {
        System.out.print("\\__/ ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: your code works fine for me, what do you see in your console ?

Comment: I just tried it and it just worked for me too (openjdk on linux). It might have something to do with line-buffering since- you're using `\n` instead of `println()`.

Comment: Your code works fine to me too. What it's doing wrong?

Comment: Your posted code is definitely working. Are you sure that you are not somehow running the wrong binary?  Accidentally running a binary that is not in fact a compiled version of the code you have above?  For instance, I would suggest you add traces in `drawBox()` just for the sake of making a visible change. Then verify that the change is there when you run it, to confirm that you are running the correct binary.

Comment: When I run the program it prints the "boxes" and then nothing.  It wont move on to the pattern part.

Comment: I added a print line statement at the end of the boxes method and it wont print the new statement.

Comment: Add a print at the beginning of the boxes method.  Does that show?  OR change this line `System.out.println("Project 1 written by CHRISTOPHER TERRANOVA");` to something else.  Do you see the change?

Comment: I changed the above println and it did not show the change when executed

Comment: Then, you're either not compiling the source file after you change it, or you are not running the newly compiled code.  I don't know what IDE you are using, but your problem is there, and not in the source file.  Short of showing us some screenshots of how you are compiling and running your program, I don't think we'll be able to help you further.

Comment: I'm using Dr. Java and doing the same compile and run steps that I have used on all of the other assignments.  This is the first issue that I have had.  I thank you for all of the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfectly. You just have to enter 3 int value. I ran it with three 10 and the result is like this:

```
Enter the number of boxes desired:10
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
Enter width of the pattern:10
Enter height of the pattern:10
 __  __  __  __  __  __  __  __  __  __ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/ \__/
```

Isn't it supposed to work like this?

Comment: Exactly like that.  Mine will only execute the first method (the boxes) after printing the boxes it stops and wont begin the pattern part.

Comment: That's because it stop for you to enter 2 other int. You should enter an int when you see message below:
`Enter width of the pattern:`
and press enter which the second message for second int will be appear like below:
`Enter height of the pattern:`
when you enter it and press Enter the rest of code will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Both ran through fine on my machine only crashing when I input non-integer values. This I assume is the expected result:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:41443', transport: 'socket'
Project 1 written by CHRISTOPHER TERRANOVA

Enter the number of boxes desired:
3
+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |
|      |      |      |
+------+------+------+
Enter width of the pattern:
3
Enter height of the pattern:
3
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:41443', transport: 'socket'
 __  __  __ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ 
/ \__/ \__/ \__
\__/ \__/ \__/ 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Mine executes the boxes part and then stops.  It does not give the inputs for the pattern part.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? You can try to run it in the debugger.

Comment: I don't know much of anything about Dr. Java but here are a couple of things to try and narrow down on the problem. 1) Delete (or rename) the existing compiled Patterns.class file 2) recompile and see if the new file shows up where you expected it to 3a) if so run it and the changes you've made should now show up 3b) else find out where it's output too or why it hasn't compiled.